# Photoshop: navigation hidden, how to bring it back

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shortcuts

In my photoshop CS6 the navbar is hidden. How can I get it back?

[image]

Comment: Question makes no sense.. your image show the navigation bar.

Answer (score 2):

It's called the [Options bar](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/using-tools.html#using_the_options_bar) and can be shown and hidden from the Window menu:

> Window → Options

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>F</kbd> to bring back a full view.

If that doesn't work, try going to "Main menu > Window > Workspace" and play with the options there.

Comment: Thanks Lucian, I do this but it don't get back.

Comment: I edited my answer with some other thing you can try.

Answer (score 0):

Its Option tool bar

Go on Window->and then click on option which is at extreme bottom.[image]